# What is the difference between quit and exit in hive

Tags: hive, exit

Is there any difference between 'quit' and 'exit' when I exit hive?

Answer (score 4):

From [hive documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Cli#LanguageManualCli-HiveInteractiveShellCommands), it seems that quit and exit execute the exact same function of exiting the hive CLI.

Further, according to the [source code](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/cli/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/cli/CliDriver.java#L130) the two commands are functually identical.

```
if (cmd_trimmed.toLowerCase().equals("quit") || cmd_trimmed.toLowerCase().equals("exit")) {

  // if we have come this far - either the previous commands
  // are all successful or this is command line. in either case
  // this counts as a successful run
  ss.close();
  System.exit(0);

} else if (...
```

Comment: links can get broken, so it is recommended to add the relevant parts to the answer (in addition to the links)